# How to Open New blank indicator?

Tags: editor, pine-script

I just started with TradingView and I am just trying to open a blank page to start coding, but this page has some confusing info:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/primer/First_indicator.html

"Start by bringing up the “Open” dropdown menu at the top right of the Editor and choose “New blank indicator”.

Well, the problem is that there is no option called "New blank indicator" I took a screen shot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VryUL.png)

Opening in a new editor just opens the existing indicator.

How can I open a blank page?

Answer (score 1):

once you open the bottom tab on the chart screen, select Open -> Indicator on the menu :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The open menu is 2 buttons to the right of where you’re clicking (where it says “open”).

From there chops “new indicator”

Comment: Thanks - sorry, I must be blind for not seeing that, very much appreciated!